# Google login and registration in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, user-registration, google-signin, user-information-list

I am developing an asp.net web application  in vs2008 framework 3.5.I need to use google login and registration in my site.Please tel me whether i should use any api ?Is there any ways to extract the sign in information from the user who is using my site?
My intention is to create login like that in http://www.plaxo.com/.

Comment: Can u please elaborate the steps?What all things i should be done ?Should i register an app in google api to get user info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OpenId, [dotnetopenauth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) should serve your purpose.

This [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth), although for MVC, should explain to you how to use DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the user information from the example? If yes pls describe how?